# Count records based on a repeating field while returning other values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT a.uid AS uid,
  a.creation_date as creation_date,
  a.activity_date as activity_date,
  feature1 as feature1,
  feature2 as feature2,
  feature3 as feature3,   
FROM ( table a
  INNER JOIN
   table b
  ON
    a.uid=b.uid
  INNER JOIN
    table c
  ON
    c.uid=a.uid
   )
Where *certain conditions*
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

and a sample output

| uid | creation_date | activity_date | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | date1 | date1x | asdf | sfsdfd | sdsdf |
| id1 | date1 | date1x | asdf | fasaa | asdas |
| id1 | date1 | date1x | asdf | sfsdfd | asdas |
| id1 | date1 | date1x | aadf | afdsf | adfad |
| id2 | date2 | date2x | aadf | afdsd | asdas |
| id2 | date2 | date2x | aadf | adsfsdf | sdsdf |
| id2 | date2 | date2x | asdas | afdsf | adfad |
| id3 | date3 | date3x | aadf | sfsdfd | sdsdf |
| id3 | date3 | date3x | aadf | afdsf | sdsdf |

What I would also like to have is counting the number of occurrences of the uid in the output table together with the other retrieved variables.

| uid | uid_count | creation_date | activity_date | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 4 | date1 | date1x | asdf | sfsdfd | sdsdf |
| id1 | 4 | date1 | date1x | asdf | fasaa | asdas |
| id1 | 4 | date1 | date1x | asdf | sfsdfd | asdas |
| id1 | 4 | date1 | date1x | aadf | afdsf | adfad |
| id2 | 3 | date2 | date2x | aadf | afdsd | asdas |
| id2 | 3 | date2 | date2x | aadf | adsfsdf | sdsdf |
| id2 | 3 | date2 | date2x | asdas | afdsf | adfad |
| id3 | 2 | date3 | date3x | aadf | sfsdfd | sdsdf |
| id3 | 2 | date3 | date3x | aadf | afdsf | sdsdf |

If I just add a line to the SELECT statement above with `count (uid)` it's obviously needed to specify from which table, i.e. a, b, or c, the uid is coming from. Yet I want the count of the uid's from the output table that was composed by joining the three table.

Thanks a lot for all the tips on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an analytic(window) function is evaluated after **JOIN** and **GROUP BY** clause, you can simply add **COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY uid) AS uid_count** in the middle of **SELECT** list.

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT a.uid AS uid,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.uid) AS uid_count,
  a.creation_date as creation_date,
  a.activity_date as activity_date,
  feature1 as feature1,
  feature1 as feature1,
  feature1 as feature1,   
FROM ( table a
  INNER JOIN
   table b
  ON
    a.uid=b.uid
  INNER JOIN
    table c
  ON
    c.uid=a.uid
   )
Where *certain conditions*
GROUP BY 1,3,4,5,6,7
```

Note that **GROUP BY 1,3,4,5,6,7** became different from the orginal post.
(I'm not sure this **group by** is really necessary.)

Comment: I was getting the following error: "Column name uid is ambiguous", so I tries changing "uid" to "a.uid" to the like you suggested. And it seems that it is working! Thank you so much!

Comment: yes, using an alias **a.uid** you did will resolve **ambiguous** error. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE AS(your code here)
SELECT COUNT(uid) over(partition by uid),* from CTE

try this one

Comment: Yeah, that works to get the count. But I do want all other columns as well, i.e. the dates ant the features